# Dashboard using Python

Tags: python, hive, dashboard

I have a table in hive, by using the hive table, I want to create a dashboard using python. Can somebody give me solution how can I do this.

Please note that I want to use python only.

Below is the sample hive table.

entity    count   date

---

XXX        34     25-feb-2018

---

xyz        35     25-feb-2018

---

xcv        45     25-feb-2018

---

xfr        50     25-feb-2018

---

XXX        45     26-feb-2018

---

xyz        47     26-feb-2018

---

xcv        49     26-feb-2018

---

xfr        59     26-feb-2018

---

In Dashboard :
x-axis reference is entity and y-axis reference is date. This is per day basis.

Comment: Question is too broad. What is the schema of the table? How would the dashboard looks like? This is like asking an architect "I want a house that I like".

Comment: Updated question at my level best @anonyXmous

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Dash from Plot.ly? https://plot.ly/products/dash/, it's a free plot and dashboard library.